# Connect and Create Database with codefirst, error 26

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I was trying to create database from my application but I've got the error "Server was not found".

Here is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<clear/>
<add name="HireYourGuideConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="DataSource=.;Initial Catalog=HireYourGuide;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sa;Password=123456;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
```

And here is the complete error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

Comment: Please update your post with the connection string you are using

Comment: 1. Check if your server is running 2. If it is running, are you sure it's a default and not named instance?

Comment: Are you using AutoMigrations? Is it workimng, when you rename the connectionstring to _DefaultConnection_?